# set Treeview HierarchicalDataTemplate via a property

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, treeview, dependency-properties

This one is a bit complicated.  I'm trying to create a usercontrol which has a treeview and a few other controls, to create a reusable control that will be useful for other implementations.

The problem that I'm having is that I cannot figure out how to insert a HierarchicalDataTemplate defined outside the control into the treeview that is inside the control.

Outside the control here is my WPF

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="HierarchicalDataTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <masterTreeUserControl:MasterTreeUserControl 
        HierarchicalDataTemplate="{StaticResource HierarchicalDataTemplate}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectiveListViewModel.Items, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectiveListViewModel.SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        EnableAdd="False"
        ItemType="{x:Type viewmodels:LocationItem}"
        />
</Grid>
```

The MasterTreeUserControl has a HierarchicalDataTemplate DependencyProperty

```
HierarchicalDataTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("HierarchicalDataTemplate",typeof(HierarchicalDataTemplate),typeof(MasterTreeUserControl));


private static readonly DependencyProperty HierarchicalDataTemplateProperty;
    public HierarchicalDataTemplate HierarchicalDataTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            return (HierarchicalDataTemplate)GetValue(HierarchicalDataTemplateProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(HierarchicalDataTemplateProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

And so far the Treeview inside the control looks like this.

```
<TreeView Name="ItemListView"
              Grid.Row="2"
              Margin="0,5,0,0"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ItemsCvs}}">
```

In other implementations of a treeview what I would normally do is HierarchicalDataTemplate in a fashion similar to this.

```
<TreeView.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
        <TextBlock Text="Hello"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.Resources>
```

However, as the HierarchicalDataTemplate is inside a dependency property, I need to somehow bind it into the Treeview.    I've had a look a round the internet (and will continue doing so) but can't having found anything relevent.

How can you inject a dependency property containing the HierarchicalDataTemplate  into the treeview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should work:

1. Add `PropertyChangedCallback` to your `HierarchicalDataTemplateProperty`.
2. In the handler, add template to control resources:

   ```
   private static void OnTemplateChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       var This = d as MasterTreeUserControl;
       var template = e.NewValue as HierarchicalDataTemplate;

       if(template != null)
       {
           This.ItemListView.Resources[new DataTemplateKey(template.DataType)] = template;
       }
   }
   ```

The only issue is that your `HierarchicalDataTemplate` has to have `DataType` set to your templated type. You should enforce that in some way (validation etc..)

Comment: That sorted it.  Thank you.